# AngularJS $Resource POST WebAPI 2

Tags: angularjs, rest, post, resources, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to post bookData to my WebAPI2 service by using the "$resource" in AngularJS. This works fine when it gets a book from the BookService first, modify the book and post it to the BookService.

I'm looking for a way posting a book without getting a book from the BookService first.

First, i have created an REST-service in WebAPI2:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] string id)

public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] BookData bookData)
```

Second, in the controller i'm trying to get en post some bookdata. The BookService is injected in the Controller

```js
var bookData;
    
var book = BookService.get({ id: 1 }, function()
    {
        bookData = book;
        
    });

$scope.sendBook = function () {
    bookData.Title = 'Test REST';

    var book = new BookService(bookData);

    book.$save();
 }
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work

```js
var bookData = {Title: 'Test REST'};

$scope.sendBook = function () {
    var book = new BookService(bookData);

    book.$save();
 }
```

Comment: can you post your code for bookservice ?

Answer (score 0):

There are only some static data in it.

```
public class BookController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] string id)
    {
        BookViewModel vm = new BookViewModel
        {
            Title = "TEST REST"
        };

        return Ok(vm); 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] BookData bookData)
    {
        BookViewModel vm = new BookViewModel
        {
            Title = "TEST REST"
        };

        return Created(new Url(Request.RequestUri.ToString()), vm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've find a solution. Assign the bookData to $scope

Something like:

```js
$scope.bookData = { Title: 'Some title' };
```